# How is the IBAN created worldwide?

Tags: banking, bank-account, swift, iban

I have a big list of Account Numbers, corresponding currencies and BIC-Codes.
For every Bank I know BIC-Code and location.

Now, I am interested in calculating the IBAN for every Bank-Account, if possible.

But for calculating the IBAN, I need bank codes.
I am from germany and for german banks it was pretty easy to find bank codes and calculating IBANs.

Now, I tried it for Argentina and Austria, but for Argentina I couldn´t find any bank code. For Austria I only found bank codes with 5 digits, which seems to short.

So, where do I find Answers to the following questions:
Which country does use IBAN? Which numbers/codes are needed to calculating the correct IBAN?

Thank in advance.
Sincerely,
Julian

Answer (score 1):

> Which country does use IBAN? Which numbers/codes are needed to calculating the correct IBAN?

[Here (English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number) and [here (German)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationale_Bankkontonummer) you find the relevant info and a list of participating countries.

> Now, I tried it for Argentina and Austria, but for Argentina I
> couldn´t find any bank code.

It seems that Argentina doesn't use IBAN.

> For Austria I only found bank codes with 5 digits, which seems to short.

Why? That's exactly the correct length for Austrian bank codes: they have the format `ATpp bbbb bkkk kkkk kkkk` - five digit bank code, 11 digit account number.

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot. Is there a website, where I can search for bank codes? It seems very hard to find these informations.

Comment: You'd have to search for all countries you are interested in. There is probably somewhere a list of Austrian bank codes, somewhere else a list of Swiss bank codes, and so on.

Comment: https://www.iban.com/structure seems pretty comprehensive, @Julian. The Wikipedia article may have some additional details.